# Dec Okt Hex table c++?

Tags: c++, hex, decimal, tabular, octal

I am doing a table with 3 columns **Dec Okt Hex** in C++.

The input should be an integer, greater than or equal to 1, then print a table with three columns, where all the integers from 1 to the loaded number specified in decimal, octal and hexadecimal.

For example we input number **16** the output should be like this:

[image]

and here is my code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    
    
   while ( 1)
    {
        int varde ;
        cout << " Give the desired value (at least 1 ):";
        cin >> varde ;
        
        if ( varde <1 )
         {
           cout << varde << "Invalid value , try again! Give the desired value for the table :";
         }
         
         else
         {
             cout << " desired value " << varde << "\ n";

         }
         
      
        
          

          for (int row = 0; row < varde ; + + row )
               {
                       for (int column = 0; columnIndex < 3; + + column )
                            {
                                std :: cout << std :: December << varde << '\ t ';
                                std :: cout << std :: hex << varde << '\ t ';
                                std :: cout << std :: oct << varde << '\ t ';
                                
 
                            }
                       std :: cout << std :: endl;
    
                }
         
         
         
         
          
     }
     
 }
```

but I got this output:

[image: https://s27.postimg.org/mj8kzppnn/up2_2.jpg]

Comment: you always print varde and not the currend value ( row ) and your second for loop is useless , you display 3 colon in one time with the \t

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to output `row`, the variable you're iterating over, not `varde`, the desired maximum value, right?

```
std :: cout << std :: dec << row << '\ t ';
std :: cout << std :: hex << row << '\ t ';
std :: cout << std :: oct << row << '\ t ';
```